# PHP Grab data from URL and insert into DB not working - Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql

Doing a project for class, but I can't seem to get this to work:

```
$account = $_GET['account'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_bank (Account) VALUES ('"$accounts"')");
```

If I change that second line to:

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_bank (Account) VALUES ('TEST')");`

Then it works. I'm guessing this is an issue with quotations, but I haven't been able to find a method that works. Any guaranteed fallback on how quotations should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic PHP syntax:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_bank (Account) VALUES ('" . $accounts . "')");
or
mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_bank (Account) VALUES ('$accounts')");
```

and since you're just starting out with PHP, you should be aware of [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Adding in some attack mitigation code (e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string()`) and some comments saying WHY you're using m_r_e_s() may score some bonus points from your prof.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I'm stuck in that Java mindset. Thank for the refresher, I appreciate it.

Comment: BTW 1st query, he is using `.` to concat :p (If you don't know)

Comment: Thanks, @Mr.Alien and also thanks Marc B. That's really helpful. Thanks for the pro-tip.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Marc B's answer, you're calling the wrong variable in your mySQL statement:

```
$account = $_GET['account'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_bank (Account) VALUES ('"$accounts"')");
```

Notice `$account` being defined and your calling `$accounts` (notice the 's') in your statement.

It should be:

```
$account = $_GET['account'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_bank (Account) VALUES ('$account')");
```

Comment: I'll upvote it 1ce you remove unnecessary `"` from query

Comment: Ah yes. I just found that out the hard way when I got an entry in my db that ended up being blank. Thanks though!

Comment: @Lenin `'"$accounts"'` he edited the answer later :) `'$account'` is correct

Comment: Yeah thats why I removed my comment too. But, `'"$accounts"'` would be correct too if used like `'".$accounts."'`.